# Use Dark Unica HighCharts Theme with React

Tags: reactjs, darkmode, react-highcharts

I use Highcharts to make a spider chart with React. I want to use the theme Dark Unica of Highchart but I don't know how to use it. I tried a lot of things but it is never working.

This is my react component SpiderChart :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts-more-node'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import '../utils/styles/Highcharts.css'

function SpiderChart() {

        const axisTab=[age1, age2, age3]
    const scoreTab=[10,20,15]
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
           
           chart: {
               polar: true,
               type: 'line',
               height:500,
               width:1000
           },
       
           accessibility: {
               description: 'A spiderweb chart '
           },
       
           title: {
               text: 'Age',
               align: 'center',
           },
       
           pane: {
               size: '80%'
           },
       
           xAxis: {
               categories: axisTab,
               tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
               lineWidth: 0
           },
       
           yAxis: {
               gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
               lineWidth: 0,
               min: 0,
               max: 100
           },
       
           tooltip: {
               shared: true,
               pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}%</b><br/>'
           },
       
           legend: {
               align: 'right',
               verticalAlign: 'middle',
               layout: 'vertical'
           },
       
           series: [{
               type: 'area',
               name: 'Ages',
               data: scoreTab,
               pointPlacement: 'on'
           }],
       
           responsive: {
               rules: [{
                   condition: {
                       maxWidth: 500
                   },
                   chartOptions: {
                       legend: {
                           align: 'center',
                           verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                           layout: 'horizontal'
                       },
                       pane: {
                           size: '90%'
                       }
                   }
               }]
           }
       
           
   })}, []);

 return (
     <div>
             <figure className='highcharts-figure'>
                 <div id="container"></div>
             </figure>
     </div>
 )
}



export default SpiderChart
```

Thanks !

I tried to apply a theme by doing Highcharts.setOptions(DarkUnica) after importing DarkUnica theme but it is not working.
I also tried to do a different way to code my chart but it is not working too :

```
import 'react-highcharts'
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';


function Highc() {

    var config = {
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
          data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 295.6, 454.4]
        }]
    };
 
    return(
    <div style={{border:'solid'}}>
        blabal
        <ReactHighcharts  config = {config}></ReactHighcharts>;
    </div>
    )
    
}

export default Highc
```